# Vim hotkeys for pdf-tools in emacs?

Tags: pdf, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

---

Does anyone know how to get vim hotkeys inside pdf-tools for emacs?

I have found out it comes standard with spacemacs, but can't find any documentation to get the hotkeys with regular emacs. Thanks in advance if you can point me to the right direction.

PS. I am using EVIL mode, emacs 24, arch linux.

Answer (score 1):

Spacemacs seems to simply bind the keys they want to the respective pdf functions:

https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/layers/%2Btools/pdf-tools/packages.el#L40

They obviously use their own spacemacs way of defining keybindings, but you can just copy the keys and functions and set them however you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [evil collection](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-collection) package, which has a special setup to use [vim keybindings in pdf-tools](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-collection/blob/master/evil-collection-pdf.el). Although, you must take into consideration that you would have some issues with [strange pdf blinking behavior](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/201). For fixing that, I mix the info I found [here](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/pull/1107) and [here](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/892):

```
(add-hook 'pdf-view-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
        (set (make-local-variable 'evil-normal-state-cursor) (list nil))
        (internal-show-cursor nil nil))
        ))
```

Nonetheless, the pdf will start blinking when you highlight part of the pdf. Hope this help!